# User input stored into array and prints categorized results in PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, user-input

I have to write a program where a user inputs the name and number of new memberships.  This info is stored in an array.  Specifically, the user enters a trainer's last name and the number of new memberships.  They do this for 15 different names and the output is the number of trainers falls into 1 of 3 categories:  0-5 new members, 6-10 new members, and 11-15 new members.  I cannot get the output statement to read the count for each category and output the correct statements.

```
from array import *

NewMembers1 = []
NewMembers2 = []
NewMembers3 = []
count1 = 0
count2 = 0
count3 = 0
totcount = 1

while totcount <= 4:
    t = input(str(f"Enter Trainer {totcount} Name: "))
    n = int(input(f"Enter Trainer {totcount} # of enrollees: "))
    L = [t, n]
    totcount += 1

for i in L:
    if n <= 5:
        count1 = +1
        if type(i)==int:
            i=int(i)
            NewMembers1.append(i)
        
     #   print(len(NewMembers1))

            #print(str(count1)+" trainers have 0-5 new enrollees")
    elif 5 < n <=10:
        totcount+=1
        if type(i)==int:
            i=int(i)
            NewMembers2.append(i)
            count2+=1
            #print(str(count2)+" trainers have 6-10 new enrollees")
    else:
        totcount+=1
        count3=+1
        NewMembers3.append(i)
        #print(str(count3)+" trainers have 11-15 new enrollees")


    print(str(len(NewMembers1)) + " trainers have 0-5 new enrollees.")
    print(str(len(NewMembers2))+" trainers have 6-10 new enrollees.")
    print(str(len(NewMembers3))+" trainers have 11-15 new enrollees.")
```

Comment: If this is how the code is in your file, you have to look at the indentation of the `for` loop and its contents. It seems that it should be inside the while loop. As for your `print` statements, they are in the `while` loop when they should be outside of it.

Comment: The `while` loop keeps overwriting `L` each time. At the end of the loop it just has the last trainer name, not all of them.

Comment: You aren't getting the correct answer because you are overwriting L every time you ask the user to input the data.

You will need to collect all the responses and store it in a suitable data structure, without overwriting it.

Comment: I don't see where you're creating any arrays, either. `[]` is a list, not an array.

Comment: As an aside, why are you doing `from array import *`??? Don't do that. You almost certainly don't want anything to do with the `array` module, and if you did, you certainly shouldn't be using starred imports.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = []
for i in range(1, 5):
    t = input(f"Enter Trainer {i} Name: ")
    n = int(input(f"Enter Trainer {i} # of enrollees: "))
    L = [t, n]
    data.append(L)

NewMembers1 = []
NewMembers2 = []
NewMembers3 = []

for trainer in data:
    n = trainer[1]
    if n <= 5:
        if type(n) == int:
            NewMembers1.append(trainer)
    elif 5 < n <= 10:
        if type(n) == int:
            NewMembers2.append(trainer)
    else:
        if type(n) == int:
            NewMembers3.append(trainer)

print(f"{len(NewMembers1)} trainers have 0-5 new enrollees.")
print(f"{len(NewMembers2)} trainers have 6-10 new enrollees.")
print(f"{len(NewMembers3)} trainers have 11-15 new enrollees.")
```

Comment: In this answer, data is a list of lists where each sublist contains the name of a trainer and the number of enrollees. The code then iterates through each sublist and assigns the number of enrollees to variable n. Based on the value of n, the sublist is appended to one of the three lists NewMembers1, NewMembers2, or NewMembers3.

Finally, the code prints the length of each of the three lists to show the number of trainers falling into each category of enrollee count.